# How to extract HashMap from Bundle without cast?

Tags: android, casting, hashmap, bundle

Communicating between two threads, I use a Message, transporting the data. In my case, a HashMap. Now on reconstructing the data, I get a warning about an unchecked type cast. That would imply to me (as java noob), that I shouldn't do that cast at all, right? But what would be the correct way to get the HashMap out of the bundle?

```
    Bundle dataBundle = msg.getData();
Serializable result = dataBundle.getSerializable("data");
HashMap<String,String> output = (HashMap<String, String>) result;
```

Thanx for any pointers!
Marcus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So with your approach

```
getSerializable("data");
```

there is no way to do it without casting because `getSerializable` method always returns `Serializable` instance.

Without casting you could use `getParcelableExtra` that returns `T` but i know anything about your application context so i'm not sure if it's possible to use.

Comment: so, do the cast or go for another solution?

Comment: if it works fine, there is no reason to use another solution.